# Rails Postgres ILIKE in reverse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Is it possible to match a full string to something a little less in the DB?

Basically, I might have a string like "`Microsoft Windows XP Home Edition`" or "`Microsoft Windows XP SP2`", but in my DB I have "`Microsoft Windows XP`".

Currently, I'm using `ILIKE`:

`Issue.where(type: :os).where("name ILIKE ?", "%Windows XP SP2%")`

Which doesn't find a match since the `SP2` portion doesn't exist.

So, is there some functionality that would allow me to put something generic in the DB field as I have, and figure out a match if the input is much more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use PostgreSQL [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch.html) in this case:

Example query:

```
Issue.where("to_tsvector(name) @@ to_tsquery('Windows|XP|SP2')")
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work... the `name` entry in my DB is 'Microsoft Windows XP' and what I'm bumping against the DB via your suggestion is `Windows XP SP2`.  In this case, I would be expecting `Windows XP` to be the match.  `Issue.where(type: :os).where("name ~* ?", "Windows XP SP2")`.  Returns nothing.

Comment: Yes, you're right. You need to look at full text search. Simple example `Issue.where("to_tsvector(name) @@ to_tsquery('Windows|XP|SP2')")`

Comment: That worked... I'll just have to delimit the spaces before dropping to the DB statement.  Want to update your answer?